# Covariance confusion. Can't assign tuples of implemented interfaces to list of tuples

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance, invariance

*Preface: I am aware that there are a lot of questions and answers about covariance and contravariance but I'm still feeling muddled and not sure what solution to implement.*

I have two interfaces whose implementations are intended to be used together in pairs. One provides the information about a sales item and one provides language dependent information for a sales item.

**I do not have control over these interfaces**:

```
public interface IItem
{
    decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public interface IItemTranslation
{
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

I also have two implementations of both these interfaces for a tangible `GoodsItem` as well as an intangible `ServiceItem`. Again, **I do not have control over these interfaces**:

```
public class GoodsItem : IItem
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; } //implementation
    public float ShippingWeightKilograms { get; set; } //Property specific to a GoodsItem
}

public class GoodsTranslation : IItemTranslation
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } //implementation
    public Uri ImageUri { get; set; } //Property specific to a GoodsTranslation
}


public class ServiceItem : IItem
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; } //implementation
    public int ServiceProviderId { get; set; } // Property specific to a ServiceItem
}

public class ServiceTranslation : IItemTranslation
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } //implementation
    public string ProviderDescription { get; set; } // Property specific to a ServiceTranslation
}
```

As I said, these are classes that I do not have control over. I want to create a generic list of these pairings (`List<Tuple<IItem, IItemTranslation>>`) but I cannot:

```
public class StockDisplayList
{
    public List<Tuple<IItem, IItemTranslation>> Items { get; set; }

    public void AddSomeStockItems()
    {
        Items = new List<Tuple<IItem, IItemTranslation>>();

        var canOfBeans = new Tuple<GoodsItem, GoodsTranslation>(new GoodsItem(), new GoodsTranslation());

        var massage = new Tuple<ServiceItem, ServiceTranslation>(new ServiceItem(), new ServiceTranslation());

        Items.Add(canOfBeans); //illegal: cannot convert from 'Tuple<GoodsItem, GoodsTranslation>' to 'Tuple<IItem, IItemTranslation>'
        Items.Add(massage); //illegal: cannot convert from 'Tuple<ServiceItem, ServiceTranslation>' to 'Tuple<IItem, IItemTranslation>'    }
}
```

**Question**: Without changing my `IItem` and `ITranslation` classes or their derived types, what's the cleanest way to be able to pass around a generic list of these pairings without casting them back and forth between the interface and their type?

Caveat. I was trying to simplify the question but I'm not actually using Tuples. In reality I'm using a class like this:

```
public class ItemAndTranslationPair<TItem, TItemTranslation> where TItem : class, IItem where TItemTranslation : class, IItemTranslation
{
    TItem Item;
    TTranslation Translation;
}
```

and my services are returning strongly typed lists, like `List<ItemAndTranslationPair<GoodsItem, GoodsTranslation>>` and therefore when I add items to the 'generic' list it looks like:

```
var differentBrandsOfBeans = SomeService.GetCansOfBeans();
//above variable is of type IEnumerable<ItemAndTranslationPair<GoodsItem, GoodsTranslation>>

var items = new List<ItemAndTranslationPair<IItem, IItemTranslation>>();
items.AddRange(differentBrandsOfBeans);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `out` modifier on the type parameter of the generic type to obtain *covariance* in that parameter.

In the current version of C#, this is not supported for `class` types, only `interface` types (and delegate types), so you would need to write an interface (notice use of `out`):

```
public interface IReadableItemAndTranslationPair<out TItem, out TItemTranslation>
  where TItem : class, IItem
  where TItemTranslation : class, IItemTranslation
{
  TItem Item { get; }
  TItemTranslation Translation { get; }
}
```

Note that the properties cannot have a `set` accessor since that would be incompatible with the covariance.

With this type, you can have:

```
var differentBrandsOfBeans = SomeService.GetCansOfBeans();
//above variable is of type
//IEnumerable<IReadableItemAndTranslationPair<GoodsItem, GoodsTranslation>>

var items = new List<IReadableItemAndTranslationPair<IItem, IItemTranslation>>();

items.AddRange(differentBrandsOfBeans);
```

It works because `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant, and your type `IReadableItemAndTranslationPair<out TItem, out TItemTranslation>` is covariant in both `TItem` and `TItemTranslation`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But how would I actually instantiate one of these pairings? e.g. inside the `GetCansOfBeans()` method what implementation of `IReadableItemAndTranslationPair` do I use? This is where I'm getting lost with other online QAs for covariance and the `out` modifier.

Comment: @Zac You should have a class such as ` class ItemAndTranslationPair<TItem, TItemTranslation>` which implements the `IReadableItemAndTranslationPair<IItem, IItemTranslation>` interface. The class could have both `get` and `set` for its properties (only the `get` part would be part of the interface "contract"). The return type of the `GetCansOfBeans()` method should involve the interface only, but the actual pairs you "yield" should be instances of the class.

Comment: Cheers @Jeppe. Having both the `get` and `set` part on the implementation whilst only having `get` on the contract was where I was getting confused. I can live with my `GetCansOfBeans()` method returning the interface, although my other methods like `DeleteCansOfBeans(IEnumerable<ItemAndTranslationPair<GoodsItem, GoodsItemTranslation>>)` will presumably no longer work with those lists, which seems unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the tuples using the interface types:

```
var canOfBeans = new Tuple<IItem, IItemTranslation>(new GoodsItem(), new GoodsTranslation());
var massage = new Tuple<IItem, IItemTranslation>(new ServiceItem(), new ServiceTranslation());
```

As you're storing them in a list of `Tuple<IItem, IItemTranslation>` this should be a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Sean. I've added a caveat to my answer. But essentially the service layer is returning the strongly typed pairings. I also updated the answer to show how I'm really trying to represent these pairings, it's not actually a Tuple but a class with generic type parameters. I'm trying to avoid casing back to the interface when adding these items to the list.

Comment: @Zac You cannot avoid having them typed as the interface, rather than the underlying type, because that's what the `List` requires.